# how Effective is k6 load testing for frontend part and how can we use it?

Tags: load-testing, k6

Effectiveness of k6 load testing for frontend

I am try to implement K6 for frontend? but I don't know How effective it is for frontend ? and how can we use k6 load testing for frontend ?

Answer (score -1):

What is it exactly that you want testing in your frontend? What do you want to measure with your tests? Are you looking to ensure that existing functionality  still works between different releases?

[xk6-browser](https://github.com/grafana/xk6-browser) might be worth an explore. It can be used to test your website's frontend, while also load testing your backend systems. When i say test your frontend, i mean you can navigate to it, interact with it, and assert that certain things are occurring.